# How to use OR in a regex expression for Java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to accept this both cases, `I_LOVE_TO_CODE.txt` or `I_LOVE_TO_CODE_20151125.txt`. I know how to do for each one of them separately:

```
^I_LOVE_TO_CODE.txt$
^I_LOVE_TO_CODE_\d{8}\.txt$
```

But how can I insert an `OR` condition in one single regex ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, you do not need an `|` (*OR*) operator because it would be an inefficient solution. The `^I_LOVE_TO_CODE_\d{8}\.txt$|^I_LOVE_TO_CODE\.txt$` involves much backtracking. You could contract it to `^(I_LOVE_TO_CODE_\d{8}\.txt|I_LOVE_TO_CODE\.txt)$` (where anchors apply to both subexpressions but are used once), or `^I_LOVE_TO_CODE(_\d{8}\.txt|)$` - which is already much better, *but* alternation can be avoided here altogether using **optional grouping**.

Use an optional group here like this:

```
^I_LOVE_TO_CODE(?:_\d{8})?\.txt$
               ^^^      ^^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZ4aL7/1)

The `(?:_\d{8})?` means *match an underscore followed with 8 digits one or zero times, but do not capture the substring*. Unless you need to use the value, you can do without a capturing (`(_\d{8})?)` group.

More details on [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and [optional items](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) is available at [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Comment: WOW! That was fast! Thank you sir!

Comment: I have added more explanations and links.

Comment: @MadushanPerera - Almost great stuff. I guess Tianhe-2 supercomputer would have beaten him :P

Comment: Actually, it took me 6 minutes. I started with stating a solution with the regex, then added a demo link, then some explanations, then more details on other possibilities to achieve current goal, and then added some reference links. My usual answering style.

Comment: Just a note on Java usage: backslashes must doubled and anchors are not necessary with `.matches()`. E.g. [`System.out.println("I_LOVE_TO_CODE_12345678.txt".matches("I_LOVE_TO_CODE(?:_\\d{8})?\\.txt"));`](https://ideone.com/npHA6W) => `true`

Comment: Just a "funny" note on my style: I see that [someone downvoted this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33914261/3832970) right because of my answering style.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of the patterns you are trying to match here, where one pattern is the same as the other, just with "a bit added in the middle", you can use an optional group, as stribizhev suggests.

If you are trying to match either of two (or more) things in general, you can use the `|` operator, as described in the [Pattern javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical):

```
"^(?:foo|bar|baz)$"
```

would match either `"foo"`, `"bar"` or `"baz"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly your question. In regular expressions you can use `|` to determine the value before the `|` or the value after.

You can save both in different vars like:

```
String var01= "your route to the .txt file";
String var02= "your route to the .txt file";
String regex= "your regex";
```

Afterwards, you can use an `if` statement like:

```
if((var01||var02).matches(regex)) {
    System.out.println("Succes!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Validation failed!");
}
```

Note that `.matches` returns a `true boolean` if the  validation has been matched succesfully.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: As you said, "should". I don't own enough reputation actually to comment there, so the only way I have to try to help others is answering directly. Sorry fot that.

Comment: I know. That's why I didn't *downvote* your answer :). We all (I guess even Jon skeet) started there :P

Comment: @FerranBuireu: I will upvote if you add more information about how to use `|` to achieve the result OP needs. Right now, it is a pure comment.

Comment: @FerranBuireu - I am sorry I can't do that right now. Like * stribizhev* says, if you add more info, I will definitely upvote :)

Comment: Here you are ;) @MadushanPerera

Comment: This code is a resume of how it can be resolved the issue, isn't the solution exact because I don't have the paths to the files, packages, libraries and whatever imported here, but I've tried a very similar one a few days ago and worked perfectly.

Comment: [The code won't compile](https://ideone.com/JyWhXv): *error: bad operand types for binary operator '|'*. To check if your code works, you can rely on [IDEONE.com](http://ideone.com), [EVAL.in](http://eval.in), or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm. I think there are much more.

Comment: @Ivar this is not C#. Use | (or) in if statements has a lot of sense.

Comment: Of course it does not work if you don't create the variables

Comment: You are right. Never the less is it still a [bitwise OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), also in Java.

Comment: I will check as soon as I can, anyway. The doubt has been resolved so there's no point to keep discusing this.

Comment: @Ivar Use a conditional like if with an | (or) is perfectly valid. If one statement or another validates the condition, do the following instructions. I don't understant why you said that. Anyway, as I said, the doubt has been cleared and there's no way to keep discusing.

Comment: With a [Conditional-OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) (||) you are right, but you are not using that in your example. That may be something worth noting. A single | is used for a bitwise OR, and does not work on a String, which is why your code fails to run.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realized that, my fault. Edited.