# Find words with capital first letter, that are grouped together

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find words within a string that is single, or grouped together.

For example:

```
This is a String That is my example, Here Is More text as example.
```

I want to take out so my result is the following.

```
This
String That
Here Is More
```

The regex I have so far is this

```
(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\s\b)
```

This finds capitalized words but only groups them separately containing the space. How can control the regex to *accept 1 to 3 words in a row, with capital letters*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+` on the group to match more than one occurrences.

```
(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\s\b)+
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aO9cW9/1)

Use `{1,3}` to match words in one, two or three groups.

```
(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\s\b){1,3}
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aO9cW9/3)

Comment: Welcome @KayNelson. This also selects the trailing space, if you dont' want it check other answers.

Comment: It is good to use with ASCII input and in case trailing whitespace is not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

A truly Unicode supporting solution is

```
\b(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)*(?:\s+(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)*){0,2}\b
```

It will only match 1-3 capitalized words at a row without leading/trailing whitespace.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3E%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D*)(%3F%3E%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D*)*(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B(%3F%3E%5Cp%7BLu%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D*)(%3F%3E%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BM%7D*)*)%7B0%2C2%7D%5Cb&i=This%20is%20a%20String%20That%20is%20my%20example%2C%20Here%20Is%20More%20Text%20as%20example.)

Here is the explanation:

- `\b` - word boundary (there should be a non-word character before it)
- `(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)*` - a word starting with an uppercase letter (followed by optional diacritics) then followed with any (precomposed, too) Unicode letters
- `(?:\s+(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)*){0,2}` - 2 to 0 occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces (`\s+`) followed by...
  - `(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)*` - a word consisting of Unicode letters (potentially with diacritics).

The `\p{Lu}` matches uppercase Unicode letters. The `\p{M}` matches diacritics. So, to match a capitalized Unicode letter, use an atomic group `(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)`. `\p{L}` matches any base Unicode letter. So, a word will be sum total of the subpatterns `(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)*`.

[C# code](http://ideone.com/cVFXso):

```
var line = "This is a String That is my example, Here Is More Text as example.";
var pattern = @"\b(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)*(?:\s+(?>\p{Lu}\p{M}*)(?>\p{L}\p{M}*)*){0,2}\b";
var result = Regex.Matches(line, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Result: `This`, `String That`, `Here Is More`, `Text`

Comment: Regex in .NET is Unicode-aware, that is why when answering I assumed  you should be interested in full Unicode support. It goes without saying you need to use a verbatim string literal when using the regex in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Define a second pattern and repeat it zero or more..

```
@"\b[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]*)*\b"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aO9cW9/2)